# Need to report a site copying SO without attribution

Tags: support, attribution, copycat-sites

Example:

http://ask.programmershare.com/2672_5725993/

is a copy of

[How do I force bjam in boost to build cleanly and consistently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709105/how-do-i-force-bjam-in-boost-to-build-cleanly-and-consistently)